# Angular JS - Text box not getting updated after clearing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am a beginner in Angular JS. While creating a sample application I have encountered the below problem of a text box not getting set once the value in its cleared using JavaScript.Below is my code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

     app.controller("myCtrl", function () {

        this.showName = function () {
            this.user = { name: "John" };
        }

        this.clear = function () {

            document.getElementById("name").value = "";

        }
    });
</script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
 <div ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl" class="container">

    <input type="button" ng-click="ctrl.showName()" value="Show Name"/>
    <input type="text" id="name" ng-model="ctrl.user.name" />
    <input type="button" value="Clear" ng-click="ctrl.clear()" />

 </div>
</body>
```

Her the first time I click on the Show name button I am getting the name in the text box.But if I clear the text box by clicking the Clear button and then click on the show button again the name is not getting filled in the text box.
Can anyone please tell me why this is happening and anyways to fix this?

Here is my code in plunkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/MXlH2o?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your clear function do below code to clear value.

```
this.user = { name: "" };
```

Comment: Thanks Mohit. This works but can you please tell the reason why my code was not working?

Comment: Yes, actually in Angular when you clear any field by getting that element, in that case ng-model is blocked and then two way binding does not work that's why It was not working.

Answer (score 1):

Clear the name like this,

```
this.clear = function () {
                this.user.name = "";
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need a clear() method in the controller, just take advantage of the double binding in angular, set the username to an empty string when you click on the button and the view will be updated consequently.

```
<input type="button" value="Clear" ng-click="ctrl.user.name = ''" />
```

Comment: Thanks Karim. But can you please tell the reason why my above code is not working?

Comment: Well, I just don't think it's the right way to use angular. With angular you should not manipulate dom in this way to avoid messing with the native javascript but use the tools provided. cheers

Answer (score 1):

change clear function to this code

```
this.clear = function () {
     this.user.name="";
}
```

Comment: @Bamnaam, can you also tell OP the reason he needs to do so? Answers in Stackoverflow are meant to be quite clear and descriptive. So keep that in mind.